# unable to listen to node app

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm trying to make an app with node using express and socket.io, but i've run into a problem. In terminal when I type node app.js it says that "TypeError: Object # has no method 'listen'" reffering to hte line `io.listen(http);` Whats wrong here?

**Error**

```
/Users/peter/Dropbox/testapp/app.js:15
http.listen(3000);
     ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'listen'
```

**Code**

```
    // express module
var express = require('express'),
    // http module
    //http = require('http').createServer(app).listen(3001),
    http = require('http'),
    // socket.io module
    //io = require('socket.io').listen(http);
    io = require('socket.io'),
    // node onject
    app = express();

// create server
http.createServer(app);
//listen to server on port 3000
http.listen(3000);
// listen to http server object
io.listen(http);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line you say is the problem isn't the line the output says is the problem, but they are both kind of the same problem.

`listen()` isn't part of `http` but of the object `ceateServer()` returns (of type `http.Server`). That is also the issue with the socket.io bit as well though, they are both expecting the actual server object. What i think you want is:

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
io.listen(server);
server.listen(3000);
```

From looking at the commented out code, I can see why this probably got mixed up.